# How to get Phonegap up and running on OS X

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I have decided to port my Appgyver Supersonic Hybrid app over to Phonegap as it seems that Phonegap is more stable. I'm having problems getting a workflow setup. What I would like is to be able to have some sort of livereload feature available with the ability to get to the webviews themselves in Chrome. I tried to use Weinre in Phongap Build but it's showing "none" for targets and I cannot get it to work.

The Phonegap developer app works... sorta but the livereload function doesn't work and when it does work it takes quite some time to reload in the app on the phone.

My workflow before with Appgyver was pretty good, I used their developer app in Genymotion and google remote debugging. Any changes made to the app's source would trigger a reload on all devices.

If anyone can help me get up and going with Phonegap on OS X I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

For my workflow on OS X I am using Cordova, XCode and GapDebug. I use Cordova to create the iOS project and XCode project file:

```
`cordova platform add ios`
```

and then open the .xcodeproj file in XCode and do my editing there. Once you've hooked up your iOS device via USB, you can deploy+run your app on the device from within XCode, and then use GapDebug to debug it with breakpoints, DOM inspection, etc.: https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/

While this is not the "live reload" feature that you are asking for, once you get into the edit/deploy/run/debug flow it only takes about 5 seconds to deploy and run the app, which is pretty sweet.